# function calling from a different class

Tags: c++

Here is a skeleton code:

```
class C{
  callMe(){}
};

class A{
  // How to use callMe()
};

class B : C {
  callMe();
  A a;
};
```

In this example class B extends class C, so it can call callMe() method. But I need to use callMe() using class A given that class A can not extend class C. I wonder how?

Comment: Well, this is far from `C++` code. And even more far from `C`.

Comment: Can you make the function public? If not, you can use `friend`. C also doesn't have classes in the sense that you can inherit from them without some extra work.

Comment: I just put a skeleton...

Comment: You are missing a return type on `callMe();`. If `B extends C` you don't need to redeclare `callMe();` either. Lastly, you will need to have an instance of C inside A to call the `callMe();` method of that instance AND declare it in C as `public` OR declare A as a friend of C (Since `callMe();` is not __static__ nor __public__ by default). Are you familiar with concepts of Object Oriented Programmation ?

Comment: Redesign you object model ... Or don't use Object Oriented design if you don't use it as its meant to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make A contain an object of type C.

```
class A
{
 private:
   C objC;

 public:
   void WhateverMethod() { objC.CallMe(); }

};
```

Also, the syntax for inheritance is

```
class B : C{

};
```

If you want B to simply have access to CallMe(), then you do not need to redefine it in B. It will inherit it from C. If you want B to override CallMe then you need to do this:

```
class C
{
  public:
    virtual void CallMe() { //definition }

};

class B : public C
{
 public:
   void CallMe() { //redefine it here }

};
```

Note, I assume from your syntax errors that you are a JAVA programmer. Methods are not automatically marked as virtual in C++, you have to mark them as virtual if you want to use polymorphism, and you have to use them from a pointer for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
class C{ 
  callMe(){} 
friend class A;
}; 


class A{

//use call me here

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an instance of `C`:

```
class C {
public: // has to be public
  void callMe() const {}
};

class A{
public:
    A(const C& inst) : inst(inst) {}

    void foo() {
        inst.callMe();
    }
private:
    const C& inst;
};
```

Comment: That will not compile, unless you make `callMe` const member function, or alternatively, save `inst` as non-const reference.